# buildozer android NDK not downloading Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, android-ndk, kivy, buildozer

I'am using the OS Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have installed the buildozer in the python2 and python3.The android sdk is installed but the buildozer is showing error while downloading android NDK.Please do help me to solve this issue.
Following is the **Error.**

```
  # Downloading http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r9c-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fadii/.local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer-0.33.dev0-py3.5.egg/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer-0.33.dev0-py3.5.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1026, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer-0.33.dev0-py3.5.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 91, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer-0.33.dev0-py3.5.egg/buildozer/target.py", line 101, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.prepare_for_build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer-0.33.dev0-py3.5.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 175, in prepare_for_build
    self.target.install_platform()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer-0.33.dev0-py3.5.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 499, in install_platform
    self._install_android_ndk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer-0.33.dev0-py3.5.egg/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 309, in _install_android_ndk
    cwd=self.buildozer.global_platform_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/buildozer-0.33.dev0-py3.5.egg/buildozer/__init__.py", line 671, in download
    urlretrieve(url, filename, report_hook)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1760, in retrieve
    block = fp.read(bs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tempfile.py", line 622, in func_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem. When I tried the address of the NDK I found that google had changed the URL to the NDK.

Buildozer is configured with:
http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r9c-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2

But currently it is:
http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9c-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2

The solution is to manually download the ndk from the working URL, unpack it and place the unpacked folder as new subfolder into:

```
/home/<your-user>/.buildozer/android/platform/
```

Comment: Glad to hear that! However: if you encounter more issues you should perhaps also consider trying to use a specific version of builddozer via: 1) `git clone https://github.com/kivy/buildozer` 2) cd into the directory and get a specific release e.g.: `git checkout tags/v0.32` 3) `python setup.py build`

Comment: The current download link appears to have a corrupted archive file as I've downloaded it 10 times to check. Please let me know if there is nay other link available.

Comment: What do you recommend for those of us using the buildozer VM? We don't have .buildozer under the kivy user

Answer (score 0):

You can download latest NDK from below mentioned Link. Install according to os.
    https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in kivy master: https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/commit/7fb6535c08e92ae9e93e590e1875db3818ec15f6

So should work from master now.