# cannot install NDK

Tags: python, android-ndk, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to use buildozer for my python-kivy app. When I run the code "buildozer android debug deploy run" I got an error:

## Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 17c

## Android NDK is missing

So I did all the steps here:
    [buildozer android NDK not downloading Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097586/buildozer-android-ndk-not-downloading-ubuntu)

(I used NDK 17c based on my error hint)

But still, I have the same error: # Android NDK is missing

The ls of my platform are these:

android,  ndk-build, README.md, android-ndk-r17c-linux-x86_64.zip, ndk-depends,  shader-tools,android-ndk-r20b,  ndk-gdb,  simpleperf, android-sdk, ndk-stack, source.properties, apache-ant-1.9.4, ndk-which, sources, build, platforms, sysroot, CHANGELOG.md,prebuilt, toolchains, meta, python-packages, wrap.sh

So, I have ndk!  what shoud I do?  (my system is ubuntu)

Comment: any comments? or should I clear my problem?

Comment: I think you need to unzip `android-ndk-r17c-linux-x86_64.zip`.